# "set tags=./tags,tags;$HOME" not working

Tags: search, vim, directory, tags, ctags

When I try to execute `set tags=./tags,tags;$HOME` command it gives me error as below

```
-bash: /home/ram: Is a directory
```

How to get the tags to find from the parent directories ????

Comment: Do you execute that command in your shell or in Vim?

Answer (score 1):

Try this if your tag file is named `tags` under the home directory

```
set tags=./tags,tags;$HOME/**/tags
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you already executed

```
ctags -R .
```

in the root directory of your project, paste this in your .vimrc

```
set tags=tags;/
```